# Draw.io: how to change the pageBreakColor in "Extras -> Configuration" section?

Tags: app.diagrams.net, customization, configuration

Is there a way to set the pageBreakColor usgin the Configuration section? sometimes the actual color is not visible in small 13" screens or it looks like grid color.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not supported. Check the list of features you can configure: https://www.drawio.com/doc/faq/configure-diagram-editor